# CSS effects work fine with static table data, but not when table data is added by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table in my html document that is styled with css.  When I hard code the table rows and cells in html, the styling is working as desired.  For example when I hover the mouse over a row, the coloring changes.

The problem is when I add all the table rows and cells via javascript, the hovering effects no longer work.  The curious thing is, if I leave the static data, and also add data via javascript, the styling works fine.

How can I get the styling to work correctly when I want to populate all the data of the table via javascript?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="JobPercentCompleteTable">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Job Number</th>
  <th>Total Hours</th>
  <th>Completed Hours</th>
  <th>% Complete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<!-- Static Row -->
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td> 
</tr>
<!-- Javascript Added Row -->
<tr>
  <td>One</td>
  <td>Two</td>
  <td>Three</td>
  <td>Four</td>
  <td>Five</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the chunk of code that fills the table in the function I call on page load.

```
//Populate table
var table = document.getElementById("JobPercentCompleteTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var numJobs = obj.length

for(var i = 0; i < numJobs; i++)
{
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var jobData = obj[i];

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= rowCount;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= jobData.jobNum;
    var totalHours = (jobData.compHrs + jobData.notCompHrs).toFixed(2);
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= totalHours;
    row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= jobData.compHrs;
    var percentComp = ((jobData.compHrs / totalHours) * 100).toFixed(2);
    row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= percentComp;
    rowCount++;

}
```

As long as the static row is present, everything works, but as soon as I remove the static row and only have rows created by javascript, the hovering effect is gone.

Here is the CSS that is supposed to be in effect:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > th {
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the HTML it's outputting is exactly the same as your hardcoded version (in terms of classes, ids, elements etc?)

Comment: The HTML appears to be exactly the same.  Also, the definition of the table and class is defined in the hard coded HTML, so that is never changing.  All I am doing in javascript is adding rows exactly as the static data looks.  <tr><td>1</td><td>Mark</td><td>Otto</td><td>@mdo</td></tr>.....

Comment: Hi, can we see some code ? It would be really useful to see the hard coded table rows vs the dynamically created rows. Also, can you show us your CSS definitions ?

Comment: Sorry guys, I am new here and trying to add some code in the proper way.  Stay tuned.

Comment: If you could also add your CSS, it would be great

Comment: As you do use jQuery, do you use their hover event or are you using css hover?

Answer (score 1):

The javascript I had written to add new rows to the table was actually adding them to the head section of the table and not the body.  After specifically adding the rows to the table body, styling worked as desired.  Below is the new code I use to populate the table.

```
//Populate table
      var tableBody = document.getElementById("JobPercentCompleteTableBody");
      var rowCount = tableBody.rows.length;

      var numJobs = obj.length
      for(var i = 0; i < numJobs; i++)
      {
        var row = tableBody.insertRow(rowCount);
        var jobData = obj[i];

        row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= rowCount;
        row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= jobData.jobNum;
        var totalHours = (jobData.compHrs + jobData.notCompHrs).toFixed(2);
        row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= totalHours;
        row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= jobData.compHrs;
        var percentComp = ((jobData.compHrs / totalHours) * 100).toFixed(2);
        row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= percentComp;
        rowCount++;
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the problem is in the JS function that populates the table dynamically:

- If you are using ID's to bind the hover event listener to the rows, make sure that the generated rows have the expected IDs and you have all the event listeners in place.
- Similar case if you are using classes as the selector to bind the event: Make sure that the rows have the exact expected class.
- Make sure the HTML structure in your generated table is the expected: It happens that the CSS rule expects the selector to have another class wrapping the binded element. For example:

  .class1 .class2:hover{
  ...

  Wont get applied if class2 is not inside class1.

Comment: Of all the questions on SO (tagged html,css,js) I guess this applies to kind of all of them..., maybe you could be more specific and target this case special issue?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? More specific on which special issue? (wow, a downvote?)

Comment: For me your answer is to broad, as what you wrote applies on everything in a html page. Also to answer a question wich is clearly code related without have seen the code becomes to me a "wild guess", so therefore a down vote. Feel free to udpate your answer to something more valueable and the down votes goes away.